# Joins not working due to missing properties in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I imported data into the neo4j database and there were some blank values as well so while importing the data, the property didn't create into the nodes which have blank values. i.e.

Student
Name | City

Amit | Delhi

Akshay |

So 2 nodes are being created. 1 node has 2 properties and another node has a single property.

I created a relationship something like:-

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Student.csv" AS row
MATCH (e:College {College_ID: row.College_ID})
MATCH (c:Student {Name: row.Name,City: row.City})
MERGE (c)-[:REQ_TestedBy_TC]->(e);
```

Now when I'm going to join these nodes like:-

```
(c:College)-[r:CollegeHaveStudent]->(s:Student)
```

Then it is returning only the first row because the second student doesn't contain the City property so Join is not working.

I need help with what can be a workaround for that situation.

Comment: how are you going to create a relationship if you don't know between which two nodes it will be created? you can use a coalesce with default value, that's about it IMO

Comment: please describe your desired outcome (with the understanding that the dataset is incomplete...)